# Условия вывода для LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

Для простоты понимания, привожу аналогию моей таблицы.

```
SELECT (class.id)
class.name,
users.name
FROM class
LEFT JOIN users ON users.class_id = class.id
WHERE class.id = '1' limit 1
```

В таблице `users` есть колонка `date`, внимание вопрос, как можно управлять условием вывода пользователя?скажем я хочу вывести пользователя с максимальным айди или сортировать по полю `date` в обратном порядке?

Comment: а в прямом вы сортировать умеете?

Answer (score 2):

[С помощью `ORDER BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html). Самые распространённые формы употребления:

```sql
ORDER BY выражение ASC  -- по возрастанию
ORDER BY выражение      -- то же самое
ORDER BY выражение DESC -- по убыванию
```

Он задаёт порядок записей, `LIMIT` берёт указанное число первых в указанном порядке строк.

Чтобы взять **одну** запись с **максимальным** значением *чего-то*, отсортируйте записи **по убыванию** этого *чего-то* и возьмите первую из них (`LIMIT 1`).

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял смысл:

```
order by date desc nulls last
```